# Regular Expression for special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to do a regex replace on a string but it's not going as smoothly as I would hope.  I built this regular expression from a tool online and the tests show matches how I would expect, but when I run my code, I'm not getting the expected results.

My Code:

```
  Regex reg = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9-]$");
                string docName = t.Title.ToLower();
                reg.Replace(docName, "-");
```

I'm hoping that by taking a string like : `"hey! thsi is am@&4$amazing!"`
I will end up with : `"hey- thsi is am--4-amazing-`

Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: what are the results that you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-]$

            ^^
```

> $ assert position at end of a line

So yours will replace only special character just before end of line.

just use

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

Also ,this will replace even `space`.So better use

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/40

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Makes complete sense now.